# How to package PHP code like jar or exe or dll?

Tags: php, dll, jar, package, exe

How to package PHP code like jar in java or exe and dll in visual studio ?

such that when i host it my source code isn't directly available.

Comment: PHP has [phar](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.phar.php) for packaging code

Answer (score 1):

phar just packages things up into a single file, it doesn't stop the source code being visible (just open a phar file in a text editor).

If you want your code encrypting, so that even someone with access to the code can't view it, look into something like Zend Guard or Ioncube.

When you say 'When I host it my source code isn't visible' - if you're running a web application, the end user can't see your source code, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Try using an obfuscator. Have a look on this obfuscator for php (https://github.com/naneau)/php-obfuscator. There is one named [Zend-gaurd](http://www.zend.com/en/products/zend-guard), although it isn't free.